# Trying to creating a collapse/expand all button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have implemented the aligator.io "pure CSS collapsible's" to my site and I am trying to think of a way to select all of them and collapse/expand them all at once. Here is the link to the aligator.io page: https://alligator.io/css/collapsible/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="wrap-collabsible">
  <input id="collapsible" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
    <label for="collapsible" class="lbl-toggle" tabindex="0">lorem 
    ipsum</label>
      <div class="collapsible-content">
    <div class="content-inner">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In 
          consequat turpis nibh, at molestie nibh feugiat vel. Donec laoreet 
          tristique turpis ut malesuada. Maecenas ultrices posuere sem at 
          dignissim. Ut posuere, orci sed pharetra finibus, augue sapien 
          lacinia urna, convallis faucibus quam orci sit amet arcu. Nulla 
          porttitor cursus lacus ac ultrices.</p>
    </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.wrap-collabsible {
    margin-bottom: 1.2rem 0;
}
input[type='checkbox'] {
    display: none;
}
.lbl-toggle {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger, Frutiger Linotype, Dejavu Sans, Helvetica Neue, Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: #cccccc;
    background: #424874;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 7px;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out; 
}
.lbl-toggle:hover {
    color: #DC143C;
}
.lbl-toggle::before {
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: 6px solid currentColor;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: .7rem;
    transform: translateY(-2px);
    transition: transform .2s ease-out;

}
.toggle:checked + .lbl-toggle::before {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-3px);
}
.collapsible-content {
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height .25s ease-in-out;
}
.toggle:checked + .lbl-toggle + .collapsible-content {
    max-height: 350px;
}
.toggle:checked + .lbl-toggle {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.collapsible-content .content-inner {
    background: #E1DCDC;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #9A8F97;
    border-right: 3px solid #9A8F97;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    color:black;
    font-weight:600;
}
```

So I would like to place a button or 2 above the collapsible that will select each of the collapsibles and then action each of them?

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Hi please check the solution below:

I have added the button above which change the state of the toggle checkbox on click

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('collapseAll')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  var toggle = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle');
  var numtoggle = toggle.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < numtoggle; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("toggle")[i].checked = true;
  }
});


document.getElementsByClassName('uncollapseAll')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  var toggle = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle');
  var numtoggle = toggle.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < numtoggle; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("toggle")[i].checked = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.wrap-collabsible {
    margin-bottom: 1.2rem 0;
}
input[type='checkbox'] {
    display: none;
}
.lbl-toggle {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger, Frutiger Linotype, Dejavu Sans, Helvetica Neue, Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: #cccccc;
    background: #424874;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 7px;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out; 
}
.lbl-toggle:hover {
    color: #DC143C;
}
.lbl-toggle::before {
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: 6px solid currentColor;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: .7rem;
    transform: translateY(-2px);
    transition: transform .2s ease-out;

}
.toggle:checked + .lbl-toggle::before {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-3px);
}
.collapsible-content {
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height .25s ease-in-out;
}
.toggle:checked + .lbl-toggle + .collapsible-content {
    max-height: 350px;
}
.toggle:checked + .lbl-toggle {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.collapsible-content .content-inner {
    background: #E1DCDC;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #9A8F97;
    border-right: 3px solid #9A8F97;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    color:black;
    font-weight:600;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button  class="collapseAll">Collapse ALL</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button  class="uncollapseAll">Un Collapse ALL</button>
</div>


<div class="wrap-collabsible">
  <input id="collapsible1" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
    <label for="collapsible1" class="lbl-toggle" tabindex="0">lorem 
    ipsum</label>
      <div class="collapsible-content">
    <div class="content-inner">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In 
          consequat turpis nibh, at molestie nibh feugiat vel. Donec laoreet 
          tristique turpis ut malesuada. Maecenas ultrices posuere sem at 
          dignissim. Ut posuere, orci sed pharetra finibus, augue sapien 
          lacinia urna, convallis faucibus quam orci sit amet arcu. Nulla 
          porttitor cursus lacus ac ultrices.</p>
    </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  
 <div class="wrap-collabsible">
  <input id="collapsible2" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
    <label for="collapsible2" class="lbl-toggle" tabindex="0">lorem 
    ipsum</label>
      <div class="collapsible-content">
    <div class="content-inner">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In 
          consequat turpis nibh, at molestie nibh feugiat vel. Donec laoreet 
          tristique turpis ut malesuada. Maecenas ultrices posuere sem at 
          dignissim. Ut posuere, orci sed pharetra finibus, augue sapien 
          lacinia urna, convallis faucibus quam orci sit amet arcu. Nulla 
          porttitor cursus lacus ac ultrices.</p>
    </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```